# DC.JS how to animate the order of the rows in a rowchart?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a rowchart ordered by value (from greater to lesser). When filtering data, the row order changes as expected. However, the row's order change instantly.

Is there a way to animate the reordering of the rows when it changes?

I have searched for possible ways, but I couldn't find anything.

I see that each row has a class according to its position. So. the first one has the classes row _0, the next one row _1, etc., but couldn't figure out how to get the _0, _1 ... classes and using a pretransition function, such as

```
    myChart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {...}
```

to animate the order. But couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Indeed, it isn't supported - the GitHub issue is [#1170](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1160). It might be possible to fake it with events handlers, but the best way to support it would be with keyed joins [#507](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/507). It isn't hard to fix these issues but a new version will be needed because the fixes tend to break user code. I haven't found the time.

Comment: Your easiest way forward is to copy and paste `dc.RowChart` and change [this line](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/e40286013b6e20d415fe89c5e2cb1de2619a4855/src/charts/row-chart.js#L146) to use a key function, and then fix anything that breaks. You'll have to move or copy some of the attributes to after the `transition()` [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/e40286013b6e20d415fe89c5e2cb1de2619a4855/src/charts/row-chart.js#L190-L199).

Comment: Gordon, thanks. Probably this is way over my current level. I will review it later to try to understand what I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this animation was pretty simple, but testing it exposed [a major bug](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1690) in the base mixin, which I fixed. So this demo will only work with version 4.0.4.

There's no good way to implement the animation without changing the source.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/wrqLun4v/7/) copies `dc.RowChart` out to create an `AnimatedRowChart`, makes a few minor changes to locate symbols in dc.js and d3, and here are the important changes:

#### Using a key function

When adding the data, we'll use a key function,

```
        .data(this._rowData, ({key}) => key);
```

This will [join](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) the data so D3 knows which bar went where.

#### Animating the rows

Instead of just setting the positions of the rows

```
rows.attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(0,${(i + 1) * this._gap + i * height})`)
```

we'll give them an animated transition

```
    dc.transition(rows, this.transitionDuration(), this.transitionDelay())
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(0,${(i + 1) * this._gap + i * height})`);
```

I also thought it looked better if new rows start from their final position rather than the top, so I changed that as well. The resulting transitions still have plenty of issues, but they mostly make sense.

I'm not ready to release this, so it's on [a branch](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/tree/animate-row-order) of dc.js.

Here is the [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/wrqLun4v/7/) with complete `AnimatedRowChart` that you can paste into your own app.

[image: animated rows in chart]

SO doesn't seem to let my GIF loop, so reload the page if you missed it!